# jPlayer doesnt work within a Joomla Template

Tags: jquery, jplayer, joomla3.1

I've made a Joomla Template with jPlayer.

Here is the code (I made it as simple as possible, the code from the player is from jplayer.org):

```
<?php
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Chin Up!</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jplayer.org/latest/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function(event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
                    oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
                });
            },
            swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/js",
            supplied: "mp3, oga"
        });
    });
    //]]>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">

                    <!-- comment out any of the following <li>s to remove these buttons -->

                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- you can comment out any of the following <div>s too -->

                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't play the song... Nothing is going on.
The only thing that is working is that the player is visible.
I made a site with the same player offline without Joomla and it was working perfectly...

Joomla Version 3.1.1
and Joomla is running in XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution and i have no idea why this is working :D
I found a site where a jPlayer was on the site and i copied all Javascript code from it to my project...
It was working... so i deleted some of the script tags.

Now my scripts in the header look like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () { // When the jPlayer is ready to use
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://localhost/Joomla-3.1.1/images/audio/The_Hellacopters_-_In_The_Sign_Of_The_Octopus.mp3" }); // Set the file which should be played
                },
                play: function() { // When the Play-Button is clicked
                    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together
                },
                swfPath: "jplayer/Jplayer.swf", // Set the File for flash (if html doesnt work this file is the source for the player)
                supplied: "mp3", // Tell the jPlayer which file type (codec) should be used
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1", // The buttons (links) in the div with this id will take effect on this jPlayer
            });

           $("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
                ready: function () { // When the jPlayer is ready to use
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://localhost/Joomla-3.1.1/images/audio/3_Doors_Down_-_Believer.mp3" }); // Set the file which should be played
                },
                play: function() { // When the Play-Button is clicked
                    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together
                },
                swfPath: "jplayer/Jplayer.swf", // Set the File for flash (if html doesnt work this file is the source for the player)
                supplied: "mp3", // Tell the jPlayer which file type (codec) should be used
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2", // The buttons (links) in the div with this id will take effect on this jPlayer
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

The funny thing about this is that if i switch around the scripts the jPlayer isn't working.
Now it looks like that it first needs the newer Version and then the older Version.

Can anyone tell me why this is so confusing or are there so much changes between them?

Comment: I put the Version 1.10.1 before and after the jquery.jplayer.min.js and it's working too so it has nothing to do with the Versions. It's the order of the scripts...